# Right click menu triggering the click event of its parent menu-item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to add right-click menu to a menu item. I think I managed it but after clicking an item in right-click menu, menu item's click action is also firing. Any idea? Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q8nl4ypq49

Edit: My code for react component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Popup from "./Popup";
import Table from "antd/lib/table";
import Dropdown from "antd/lib/dropdown";
import Menu from "antd/lib/menu";
import { columns, data } from "./data";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item
      onClick={e => {
        alert("clicked");
      }}
    >
      click
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Like it</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Bookmark</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu mode="horizontal">
          <Menu.Item
            key="1"
            onClick={() => {
              alert("parent clicked");
            }}
          >
            <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={[`contextMenu`]}>
              <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}> right click </span>
            </Dropdown>
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const APP_NODE = document.getElementById(`container`);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, APP_NODE);
```

Comment: You need to call stopPropagation on event object because by default event's bubble up DOM tree.

Comment: Why didn't you post your example code directly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop propagate on children elements because in JavaScript click event bubble up the DOM Tree.

```
const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item
      onClick={e => {
         e.domEvent.stopPropagation();
         alert("clicked");
      }}
      click
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item >Like it</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Bookmark</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I am just curious about `e.domEvent` usage. Many people call `stopPropagation` directly from `e`, but it is not working for me. Is it about antd?

Comment: @rdonuk it's only in `antd`, in pure React you use `e.stopPropagaion()`, I've tried that first to be sure it's working in your example and it was not, so I've inspected the `e` object and found `domEvent`. It's probably in the lib docs.

Comment: Yep, `antd` needs `domEvent.stopPropagation()`